# Search in current dir only

Tags: ruby

Im using

```
Find.find("c:\\test")
```

to search for files in a dir. I just want to search the dir at this level though, so any dir within c:\test does not get searched.

Is there another method I can use ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# Temporarily make c:\test your current directory
Dir.chdir('c:/test') do
  # Get a list of file names just in this directory as an array of strings
  Dir['*'].each do |filename|
    # ...
  end
end
```

Alternatively:

```
# Get a list of paths like "c:/test/foo.txt"
Dir['c:/test/*'] do |absolute|
  # Get just the filename, e.g. "foo.txt"
  filename = File.basename(absolute)
  # ...
end
```

With both you can get just the filenames into an array, if you like:

```
files = Dir.chdir('c:/text'){ Dir['*'] }
files = Dir['c:/text/*'].map{ |f| File.basename(f) }
```

Answer (score 3):

`Find`'s `prune` method allows you to skip a current file or directory:

> Skips the current file or directory,
>   restarting the loop with the next
>   entry. If the current file is a
>   directory, that directory will not be
>   recursively entered. Meaningful only
>   within the block associated with
>   Find::find.

```
Find.find("c:\\test") do |path|
  if FileTest.directory?(path)
    Find.prune   # Don't look any further into this directory.
  else
    # path is not a directory, so must be file under c:\\test
    # do something with file
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Dir.foreach()`, for example, to list all the files under c:\test

```
Dir.foreach("c:\\test")  {|x| puts "#{x}" }
```